# Numpy vectorization instead of for loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I wrote a function which is too time consuming when used with for loops. It appends numpy vectors (10,0) as rows in each iteration. How can I use a vectorized numpy solution for the iterations to speed this up?

Any hint why the vstack-array solution below is even slower than the append-list solution?

TIA

```
import numpy as np
import time


n_iterations = 1000
n_cols = 10

def sample_func():
    # Addition: please notice: the randon function is not important. It is only an example function. The real function is more complex and needs to replace for loops by a faster numpy solution.
    row = np.random.rand(0,n_cols)
    return row



#list solution: too slow

start_time_1 = time.time()

result_list = []  
for i in range(n_iterations):
    result_row = sample_func()
    result_list.append(np.sort(result_row))

print("Run time = {}".format(time.time() - start_time_1))
    

    
#array solution: too slow

start_time_2 = time.time()

result_array = np.empty([0,n_cols]) 

for i in range(n_iterations):
    result_row = sample_func()
    result_array = np.vstack([result_array, np.sort(result_row)])

print("Run time = {}".format(time.time() - start_time_2))
```

TIA

Comment: Avoid append in general. `np.sort` does allow sort along an axis.

Comment: list append adds a reference/pointer to an existing list.  `vstack` makes a new array with full copy.  Use it just once to join a whole list arrays, not incrementally.

Comment: As long as your function is written in Python and only takes one row at a time, there isn't much you can do.  Especially if it complex, the spent evaluating that function many times will dominate.  The iteration mechanism, such as list append, will be a relatively minor time consumer.

Answer (score 1):

In general you don't want to append to `numpy` arrays.  Re-allocating space for them is too time consuming.  If you know `n_iterations`, you can allocate up-front like this:

```
result_array = np.empty([n_iterations, n_cols]) 

for i in range(n_iterations):
    result_array[i] = sample_func()
```

But you'll do much better "vectorizing" whatever is in `sample_func` to accept n-d input.  `for` loops in `python` are slow.  `numpy` gives you a lot of tricks to push your `for` loops into compiled `c`-code (called 'vectorizing'), but without knowing what's going on in the function we can't help you vectorize it.

Answer (score 0):

`np.random.rand()` is designed to return output of any shape wanted - like many other `numpy` methods. So you don't need to concatenate list of the same lengths. Try:

```
r_numbers = np.random.rand(n_iterations, n_cols)
```

And to sort all the columns:

```
np.sort(r_numbers, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

I only tried to come up with the simplest possible function sample_func to formulate the question.

My question is how to speed up the above solution considering it is for another more complex function which does not relate to random values. 

How can I replace for loops by a pure numpy solution?

Comment: @greg2021 `numpy` is not good with it. Arrays are not allowed to have unstable length unlike Python lists (or other structures), try to find a way to vectorise it (I mean find a general rule to calculate all the rows). If you need to update a list constantly, I don't know a best way because they are all doomed to be slow. But you can try more things like `np.concatenate`, list comprehension, `append` and those you proposed. It seems like `append` is promising in most of cases.